# Why do airing shows have times listed beyond a 24-hour clock?

Tags: anime-production

I know *of* the [time notation](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/OtakuOClock) for some anime—between 22:00-27:00. I know that this indicates that the show airs at a particular time, and likely targets a particular audience.

Why would this notation be used, and be preferred over a more traditional 24-hour format?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

This is a hypothesis: The time goes beyond 24 hours in order to make it easier for the viewers to identify which day of the week they should stay up late to watch the show. For example, "*Hayate no Gotoku! Cuties* is aired on **Monday 25:35**" informs the viewers that they need to stay up late on Monday.

If we write in standard 24 hours format **Tuesday 01:35**, it may cause some confusions:

- Is the show aired at 01:35 in the afternoon, or some hours past midnight?
- Some people only take note of the day of the week, but not the time: "Since it is on Tuesdays, there is no reason to stay up late on Monday".

In Japan, [both 24-hour format and 12-hour format are used *in everyday life* activity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Date_and_time_notation_in_Japan#Time). Therefore, a time without any indication of the period of the day such as **Tuesday 01:35** might be confusing. The confusion may also be partly attributed to the cultural perception about the hours of darkness.

Quoting the Wikipedia article<sup>1</sup> (emphasis mine):

<sup><sup>1</sup> The Wikipedia article lacks citation, though.</sup>

> Times past midnight can also be counted past the 24 hour mark, usually when the associated activity spans across midnight. For example, bars or clubs may advertise as being open until "26時" (2am). This is partly to avoid any ambiguity (2am versus 2pm), partly because 8the closing time is considered part of the previous business day, and perhaps also ***due to cultural perceptions that the hours of darkness are counted as part of the previous day, rather than dividing the night between one day and the next***.

---

There is another notation that is commonly used, where the day of the week is the day that the viewer has to stay up late, and the time is clamped to 24 hours with some text to clarify the time. Using the same example as above, in this notation, it will be **Monday, late night at 1:35**.

For the purpose of reference, I do a sampling from the anime of Spring 2013 season (late night shows only):

- Beyond 24 hours:

  - [Ore Imo Season 2](http://www.oreimo-anime.com/onair/index.html): チバテレビ4月6日より 毎週土曜 24:30～ 予定
  - [DATE A LIVE](http://date-a-live-anime.com/story/onair.html): TOKYO MX 4月5日より 毎週金曜日 25:30～26:00
  - [Hataraku Maou-sama](http://maousama.jp/oa.html): サンテレビにて　毎週木曜日 26:00～
  - [Ginga Kikoutai Majestic Prince](http://mjp-anime.jp/17onair/index.html): テレ玉 4月4日より、毎週木曜 25:05～
  - [Kakumeiki Valvrave](http://www.valvrave.com/): 4月11日より　毎週 （木） 25:35　放送開始
  - [To Aru Kagaku no Railgun S](http://www.project-railgun.net/index.html): TOKYO MX 毎週金曜日 24:30～
  - [Shingeki no Kyoujin](http://shingeki.tv/onair/): ＭＢＳ 4月6日より 毎週土曜 25時58分～
  - [Hyakka Ryouran Samurai Bride](http://www.hyakka-ryoran.tv/onair.html) (it uses both syntax): AT-X リピート放送 (火) 28:30～29:00
  - [Hentai Ouji to Warawanai Neko](http://www.henneko.jp/onair/index.html): MBS 毎週土曜日 26時28分～
- Clamped to 24 hours, but the day of week is the one before:

  - [Arata Kangatari](http://arata-anime.com/onair/): テレビ東京 2013年4月8日（月）から 毎週（月） 深夜 2時5分～
  - [Haiyore! Nyaruko-san W](http://nyaruko.com/onair/): テレビ東京 4月7日スタート 毎週 （日） 深夜 1:05～
  - [Hayate no Gotoku! Cuties](http://www.hayate-project.com/onair_staffcast/index.html): テレビ東京 4月8日 （月） 深夜 1時35分～
  - [Dansai Bunri no Crime Edge](http://crimeedge.com/#/broadcast): TOKYO MX 4/3 (水) ～ 毎週 （水） 深夜 0時30分～
  - [Karneval](http://karneval-anime.com/onair.html): ＡＢＣ朝日放送： 4月3日より毎週水曜深夜 2:43～
  - [PhotoKano](http://www.tbs.co.jp/anime/photokano/onair/): TBSにて毎週木曜日 深夜 1時58分～ 放送中！
  - [Yondemasuyo! Azazel-san Z](http://kc.kodansha.co.jp/azazel/onair/index.html): TOKYO MX 毎週土曜日 深夜1:00～1:15予定 2013/4/6予定
  - [Hyakka Ryouran Samurai Bride](http://www.hyakka-ryoran.tv/onair.html) (it uses both syntax): TOKYO MX 2013年 4月8日 (月) 深夜 0:30～1:00
  - [Oregairu](http://www.tbs.co.jp/anime/oregairu/onair/): TBSにて毎週木曜日 深夜1時28分～ 放送中

The usage of the 2 notations are more or less equally common. We can also observe that it is more common to specify only the starting time, than specifying both starting and ending time. The data might be skewed by the fact that all the shows here are late night shows, and the sample size is quite small (17 shows).

Comment: +1, was going to post a similar answer, but you were faster :P Also, when the time listed is "22:00-27:00", you immediately see how long will the show be, it's more convenient than trying to calculate the duration of "22:00-03:00".

Comment: @SingerOfTheFall: It is indeed easier to calculate, but do they ever specify time range? I have only see the start time in the advertisement text.

Comment: not sure, it's just a guess.

Comment: I don't see how using a standard 24 hour clock could cause confusions, as Tuesday at 01:35 is pretty straightforward to me.  However, your answer does make plenty of sense, and you've provided canonical answers in which it might be used, and it might not be.

Comment: @Makoto: In Japan, [both 24-hour and 12-hour format are used](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Date_and_time_notation_in_Japan) in everyday life, so I think this is one possible source of confusion. There is also this text in the Wikipedia page (no citation, though) `This is partly to avoid any ambiguity (2am versus 2pm), partly because the closing time is considered part of the previous business day, and perhaps also due to cultural perceptions that the hours of darkness are counted as part of the previous day, rather than dividing the night between one day and the next.`

Comment: Just as a side comment, at my job I've had to process ticketing data for movie theaters, and they tend to serve data for midnight and after showings as 24:01, 25:00 etc the previous day.  So it's not just for TV showtimes, movie theaters use that notation too.

Answer (score 15):

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/24-hour_clock):

> Time-of-day notations beyond 24:00 (such as 24:01 or 25:59 instead of 00:01 or 01:59) are not commonly used and not covered by the relevant standards. However, they have been used occasionally in some special contexts in the UK, Japan, Hong Kong and China where business hours extend beyond midnight, such as broadcast-television production and scheduling. They also appear in some public-transport applications, such as Google's General Transit Feed Specification file format or some ticketing systems (e.g., in Copenhagen). This usage prevents a time period reported without dates from appearing to end before its beginning, e.g., 21:00–01:00.

Comment: I can't recall whether time period is used in anime advertisement (I only checked a few recent ones, and they only include the starting time). However, many anime airs after midnight, so the reason `This usage prevents a time period reported without dates from appearing to end before its beginning` doesn't really apply here.

Comment: @nhahtdh Maybe not for an individual program, but when you see the entire schedule it would be confusing to see a show at `23:00-25:00` followed by a program at `01:00-01:30`.

Comment: That's true for a whole schedule, but the anime is just a single show, though. I have looked through the official website of several shows in this season to see how they specify the date. Turn out that half of them uses a slightly different notation, where the time is not beyond 24 hour.

Answer (score 5):

Whist in Japan, I've seen this happen in other places outside of anime. The opening times for one onsen was 18:00 - 20:00 for women, 21:00 - 25:00 for men.

I'm pretty sure it's to avoid the *break* that happens when switching days. It's easy to see that the men's bath is open for 4 hours, but 21:00 - 01:00 isn't so obvious at first glance.

It's also related to waking hours - if you're up at 1:00 it's more likely that you've stayed awake rather than woken up early. In that vein, keeping the same day's hours could potentially be less confusing