# What is noitaminA?

Tags: terminology

I only know that noitaminA is "Animation" written backwards. It sometimes appear at the beginning of episodes of anime.

[image: noitaminA logo]

But does it mean anything? At [Anime-Planet](http://www.anime-planet.com/tags/), it is considered a tag/genre. At [MyAnimeList](http://myanimelist.net/clubs.php?cid=6669) it is treated as a broadcast block. I don't really get it either way.

Comment: It's a programming block. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noitamina

Comment: @LoganM or student080705639 should post something like that comment as an answer so this is no an "unanswered" question.

Comment: @MarkS. Generally if I leave a comment like that, I don't intend to type a full answer, or at least it's not a high priority item. You can use it yourself if you want, though in this case the question has already been answered satisfactorily.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As [@LoganM points out in a comment](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/6366/what-is-noitamina#comment7414_6366), [noitaminA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noitamina) is a programming block on Fuji TV that initially went from 24:45-25:15 on Thursday nights (i.e. 12:45a-1:15a on Friday) and was later lengthened to 24:45-25:45.

Old noitaminA shows tended to have one major commonality - they targeted a different audience than most other late-night anime. Some good examples of this are:

- [Nodame Cantabile](http://myanimelist.net/anime/1698/Nodame_Cantabile) (a josei manga)
- [Honey and Clover](http://myanimelist.net/anime/16/Hachimitsu_to_Clover) (another josei manga)
- [Wandering Son](http://myanimelist.net/anime/8426/Hourou_Musuko) (I don't know what demographic it targets, but it addresses serious issues of gender identity, which isn't standard fare for your typical anime)
- [Genji Monogatari Sennenki](http://myanimelist.net/anime/5155/Genji_Monogatari_Sennenki) (a relatively dry adaptation of *the* classic Japanese novel)
- [Terror in Resonance](http://myanimelist.net/anime/23283/Zankyou_no_Terror) (a high-concept anime-original show with some serious political commentary, execution notwithstanding)

While the shows aired by noitaminA do not have any single unifying feature, "not being like a typical late-night anime show" is an interesting enough feature to merit a tag or genre on sites like Anime-Planet, I suppose. One other unusual feature of noitaminA shows is that they typically (though not always) last 11 or 22 episodes, rather than 12-13 or 24-26.

Some argue that the past couple years of noitaminA have been characterized by very conventional anime, rather than the mold-breakers of noitaminA's early days, thus diluting the value of noitaminA as a marker of quality. Examples:

- [Black Rock Shooter](http://myanimelist.net/anime/11285/Black%E2%98%85Rock_Shooter_(TV))
- [Guilty Crown](http://myanimelist.net/anime/10793/Guilty_Crown)
- [Robotics;Notes](http://myanimelist.net/anime/13599/Robotics;Notes)

Comment: If anyone else gets confused about the times that go beyond a 24hr clock: [Why do airing shows have times listed beyond a 24-hour clock?](http://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/4019/why-do-airing-shows-have-times-listed-beyond-a-24-hour-clock/4020#4020)